# ActionBar refresh

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am using Android compat library to show a ActionBar at the top of the screen.
The actionBar contains a refresh button which is a rotating circle if it is pressed.

To activate the rotation of the circle in the actionBar I use following:

```
getActionBarHelper().setRefreshActionItemState(true);
```

This works fine, if I call it via a button click or via onOptionsItemSelected().

But if I call it in onCreate or onStart nothing happens. I am wondering why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the rotating circle only appears once `onCreateOptionsMenu` has been executed. It means that it will not appear if you try to execute `getActionBarHelper().setRefreshActionItemState(true)` on your Activity "onCreate". If you try on "onResume" it will work. You can use it wherever you need once `onCreateOptionsMenu` has been executed.

I hope it helps you.